# Todo app javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Я сделал так, чтобы при загрузке страницы у меня выводился дефолтный список задач из массива (name: 'Сходить в магазин', done: false) в local storage. Я сделал проверку, которая в зависимости от того выполнена ли задача выставляет li правильный класс. У меня вывелись мои дефолтные задачи и помечены они все как выполненные, так же перестали работать кнопки "удалить" и "готово" + при каждой перезагрузке страницы список дефолтных дел увеличивается в 2 раза, подскажите, в чем ошибка? Мне нужно чтобы при загрузке страницы выводились мои дефолтные задачи + при добавлении нового дело оно тоже сохранялось при перезагрузке.
[image: Скрин с дефолтными зачадачами]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="todo-app.js"></script>
    <script>
        let defaultTasks = [{name: 'Сходить в магазин', done: true}, {name: 'Купить хлеб', done: false}]
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            createTodoApp(document.getElementById('todo-app'), 'Мои дела', defaultTasks);
        })
    </script>
    <title>TODO</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container mb-5">
        <nav class="nav">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Мои дела</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="mom.html">Дела мамы</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="dad.html">Дела папы</a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="todo-app" class="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
(function() {
    // Создаём и возвращаем заголовок приложения
    function createAppTitle(title) {
        let appTitle = document.createElement('h2');
        appTitle.innerHTML = title;
        return appTitle;
    }

    // Создаём и возвращаем форму для создания дела
    function createTodoItemForm() {
        let form = document.createElement('form');
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        let buttonWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        let button = document.createElement('button');

        form.classList.add('input-group', 'mb-3');
        input.classList.add('form-control');
        input.placeholder = 'Введите название нового дела';
        buttonWrapper.classList.add('input-group-append');
        button.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
        button.textContent = 'Добавить дело';
        button.disabled = true;

        buttonWrapper.append(button);
        form.append(input);
        form.append(buttonWrapper);

        input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (input.value.length > 0) {
                button.disabled = false;
            } else if (input.value.length == 0) {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        });

        return {
            form,
            input,
            button,
        };
    }

    // Создаём и возвращаем список элементов
    function createTodoList() {
        let list = document.createElement('ul');
        list.classList.add('list-group');
        return list;
    }

    function createTodoItem(name) {
        let item = document.createElement('li');
        // Кнопки помещаем в элемент, который красиво покажет их в одной группе
        let buttonGroup = document.createElement('div');
        let doneButton = document.createElement('button');
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

        // Устанавливаем стили для элемента сиписка, а так же для размещения кнопок
        // в его правой части с помощью flex
        item.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
        item.textContent = name;

        buttonGroup.classList.add('btn-group', 'btn-group-sm');
        doneButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-success');
        doneButton.textContent = 'Готово';
        deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger');
        deleteButton.textContent = 'Удалить';

        // Вкладываем кнопки в отдельный элемент, чтобы они объединились в один блок
        buttonGroup.append(doneButton);
        buttonGroup.append(deleteButton);
        item.append(buttonGroup);

        let todoItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoItems'));
        let todoItem = {name: 'Сходить за хлебом', done: false};
        todoItems.push(todoItem);
        localStorage.setItem('todoItems', JSON.stringify(todoItems));

        if (todoItem.done = true) {
            item.classList.add('list-group-item-success');
        } else {
            return item;
        }

        // Приложению нужен доступ к самому элементу и кнопкам, чтобы обрабатывать события нажатия
        return {
            item,
            doneButton,
            deleteButton,
        };
    }

    function createTodoApp(container, title = 'Список дел', arrayCases) {

        let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle(title);
        let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm();
        let todoList = createTodoList();

        if (localStorage.getItem('todoItems') == null) {
            localStorage.setItem('todoItems', JSON.stringify(arrayCases));
        }

        todoItemsDefault = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoItems'));

        container.append(todoAppTitle);
        container.append(todoItemForm.form);
        container.append(todoList);

        for (let todoItem of todoItemsDefault) {

            let todoItemElem = createTodoItem(todoItem.name, todoItem.done);

            todoList.append(todoItemElem.item);

        }

        // Браузер создаёт событие submit на форме по нажатию на Enter или на кнопку создания дела
        todoItemForm.form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            // Эта строчка необходима, чтобы предотвратить стандартное действие браузера
            // В данном случае мы не хотим, чтобы страница перезагружалась при отправке формы
            e.preventDefault();

            // Игнорируем создание элемента, если пользователь ничего не ввел в поле
            if (!todoItemForm.input.value) {
                return;
            }

            let todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.input.value);

            // Добавляем обработчики на кнопку
            todoItem.doneButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                todoItem.item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success');
            });
            todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                if (confirm('Вы уверены?')) {
                    todoItem.item.remove();
                }
            });

            // Создаём и добавляем в список новое дело с названием из поля для ввода
            todoList.append(todoItem.item);

            // Обнуляем значение в поле, чтобы не пришлось стирать его вручную
            todoItemForm.input.value = '';
        });
    }

    window.createTodoApp = createTodoApp;

})();
```

Comment: В createTodoApp: добавляете в LS todoItems, потом на пару строк ниже берёте их, проходите циклом и вызываете createTodoItem, которая каждый раз добавляет todoItems в LS - отсюда дубли. Удаление не работает потому что вы засунули его в submit..

Comment: У Вас задача 1 + 1 = 2, а решение 1 + 1 = 0. Неправильно спроектированное приложение плодит баги и костыли.